# Cauchy Schwarz equality in complex number

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I was reading Rudin Theorem 1.35 and we have Cauchy Schwartz inequality:

${\left| {\sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {{a_j}{b_j}} } \right|^2}\leqslant \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {{{\left| {{a_j}} \right|}^2}} \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {{{\left| {{b_j}} \right|}^2}} $

which ${a_j}$ and ${b_j}$ are complex numbers.

my question is when this becomes to equality?

I get to a point that they should be linear dependent but I don't know how. I tried some examples and it worked for

${a_1} = 1 + i$  ${a_2} = 2 + 2i$

${b_1} = 2 + i$  ${b_2} = 4 + 2i$

I guess ${a_i}$s should be linearly dependent and also ${b_i}$s. and both of them are multiplied by the same number(cause it didn't work with a different coefficient) but in this way, all ${a_i}$s and ${b_i}$s should be the coefficient of one complex number.

I need some help to figure out how should I find the sufficient and necessary condition for equality.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222350/complex-numbers-proving-the-equality-part-in-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-usin

Comment: Btw, it is “Schwarz,” not “Schwartz.” – [Karl Hermann Amandus Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schwarz)

Comment: @MartinR thank you. how do we know the second equation in this link?

Comment: You get that by using $|Z|^2 = Z \overline Z$.

Comment: @MartinR is there any way without using  "Lagrange identity"??

Comment: and my other question is if it is (a1,…,an)=λ(b1,…,bn), why it is working for my example?

Comment: In your example is $(a_1, a_2) = \lambda (b1, b2)$ with $\lambda = (1+i)/(2+i) = 3/5 + 1/5 i$.

Comment: @MartinR oh how didn't I notice that. thank you so much.